# How to hide the status bar on iOS in a Cinder app?

Tags: ios, show-hide, statusbar, cinder

I'm making a game with Cinder for iOS, and I have no idea how to hide the status bar. I tried calling Cinder's built-in [`hideStatusBar()`](http://libcinder.org/docs/dev/classcinder_1_1app_1_1_app_cocoa_touch.html#ae7d55049be8c4c25dbaa418437f84802) function, as well as setting the `Status bar is initially hidden` option to `YES` in my info.plist.

Neither of these methods work, even when combined. The status bar is visible both in iOS 8.1 simulator and on my iOS 7.1.2 testing device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution. You need these TWO entries in your info.plist:

`Status bar is initially hidden                 YES`

`View controller-based status bar appearance    NO`

That's it!